# Configuring SSIS packages

Tags: ssis

I have created SSIS packages. Configurations are stored within a .dtsconfig file. In order to deploy these packages to SQL Server, I am doing an Import Package (from File System) within Stored Packages.

If I make a change to the .dtsconfig file, do I need to rebuild the SSIS package and then run the Import Package again? I was wondering if there was a way to deploy an SSIS package without having to rebuild the package when a change was made to the .dtsconfig file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config is read at run-time. You just need to save the new .dtsConfig file and deploy it to where the package is looking for it.